# White space to the right of the site visible only on Desktop

Tags: html, css

I've been working on my site for quite a while now and everything has been working great up until something crashed(?).

My site shows about 47px gap to the right of the page on desktop devices and tablets but there's nothing on mobile.

This goes away when you add

```
.vc_row-fluid [class*="vc_col-"]:first-child:not([class*="offset"]) {
    margin-left: 46px!important;
}
```

However this later messes up the grid system.

I've tried to investigate the issue but no luck. This is really grinding my gears I have no clue what I should do about this.

I've tried several things like overflow-x:hidden, body min-height of 1000px, none worked....

[Screen shot #1](http://prntscr.com/8hu2r2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This css property is limiting your page width to 1100px:

```
.container, body[data-ext-responsive="false"] #boxed #header-outer[data-full-width="true"] header > .container, body[data-ext-responsive="false"] #boxed #header-secondary-outer[data-full-width="true"] > .container {
    max-width: 1100px;
}
```

Remove the above as well as this:

```
.container {
    max-width: 880px;
}
```

And finally, remove the inline negative `margin-left` from this div:

```
<div id="fws_55fdee48efaa7">
    <!--content-->
</div>
```

Comment: Your solution is very interesting, I did try it before hand however this causes every element on the page to go full screen.

Comment: huh? full-screen as in?

Answer (score 0):

First you got to remove the `margin-left` from `div id ="fws_55fdf5da42fcd"`, even on smaller screens it has negative margin. I suggest you add `margin-left:0`, i'm assuming the inline style is generated via some script

Next, Remove `margin:0 auto;` from `.container` or just set `margin:0`

Changes you'd need

```
.container, #fws_55fdf5da42fcd (or better assign a class to the div) {
margin:0;
}
```

That should fix it!